# If $Y$ is continuous and $X$ is discrete, how to write the joint density of $(Y,X)$?

Tags: density-function, joint-distribution, discrete-distributions

If $Y$ is continuous and $X$ is discrete with a finite number of points in the support, how to write the joint density of $(Y,X)$?
For example, to write the joint density function evaluated at $(Y,X)=(y,x)$, is it true that I can only write it as $f(y|x)P_x$, where $f(\cdot|x)$ is the conditional density of $Y$ given $X=x$ and $P_x$ is the marginal pmf of $X=x$.

Comment: In this instance, $X$ and $Y$ don’t _have_  a joint _density_ function in the usual meaning of the term and so there is no expression for the joint density.

Comment: Useful information can be found at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/91045, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/263506, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/134935, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/460261.  One useful way to express such distributions is described, with a detailed example, at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/296385.

Comment: @DilipSarwate Thanks! Then is there a name for $f(y|x)P_x$?

Comment: @whuber Thanks! The links are helpful.